# What is the best way to compare 2 folder trees on windows?

Tags: comparison

I'm moving a repository from sourcesafe to subversion and I need to ensure that vital points are equal. Is it any existing command / tool for windows that allows me to compare two folder trees that they are equal (has equal folder structure and files of same content)? The ideal will be something command-line like:

```
some_cool_compare c:\current_vss c:\current_svn -exclude .svn;*.vspscc;*.scc
```

Is it some tool / command exist or I need to write a script of my own?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you can use a GUI tool, the best I tried is [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) - open source.

If not, then [diff](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm) is your friend.

Comment: GUI tools are good, but currently i have a batch file that check outs vital points for both sourcesafe and subversion, and it's a lot of such points. Integrating a command-line tool to the test will be preferable.

Comment: then... diff is your friend... something like this: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm

Comment: I know this thread is old, but I came across it while looking for the exact question the OP asked. It is currently Summer 2016. I compared **WinMerge** against **ExamDiff** Pro. I prefer ExamDiff for many reasons (e.g., there is "up on folder level button"). Also, on WinMerge in the "Files and Folders" compare selector it doesn't let you choose a folder with gui (you have to paste in the folder path). I'm using the [ExamDiff 8.0](http://www.prestosoft.com/edp_examdiff.asp) Pro trial (30 days). Hope that helps some of you.

Answer (score 32):

[Beyond compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) allows you to do that and much more.

It's one of those tools I can't live without.
Take a look [here](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_scriptingref) for a reference on the scripting options

Comment: Like the OP, I was looking for a Windows folder diff tool, in particular one that could handle very large trees (100s of Gigabytes of data). Thanks [Lieven Keersmaekers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52598/lieven-keersmaekers) for the pointer to [BeyondCompare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/), which I found to be VERY fast (roughly 10-100 times faster) than my previous old school tool [windiff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDiff). BTW, BeyondCompare does have a command line mode in addition to the GUI.

Comment: A trial version of this worked pretty well for me for the one task I had. Looks like a license starts at US$30.

Answer (score 11):

You could also execute `tree > tree.txt` in both folders and then diff both tree.txt files with any file based diff tool (git diff).

Comment: Actually I found it was easier to do a `dir /s /b > flatfilelist.txt` and compare the results.

Comment: In addition with @SalmanA using fc command to compare results.

Answer (score 7):

As I am reluctant to install new programs into my machine, this PowerShell script (from [Hey, Scripting Guy! Blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/10/08/easily-compare-two-folders-by-using-powershell/)) helped me solve my problem. I only modified the path to suit my case:

```
$fso = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path F:\songs
$fsoBU = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path D:\songs
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $fso -DifferenceObject $fsoBU
```

Comment: very nice, but sloooooow :)

Comment: Extremely slow. I have one thread fully utilizing one core for a few hours without disk access. And no feedback about progress. So aborted the experiment. I need something way faster and more practical.

Answer (score 5):

[SyncToy](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=15155) is a free application from Microsoft with a "Preview" mode for comparing two paths. For example:

[image: SyncToy Preview screenshot (source: https://maketecheasier-2d0f.kxcdn.com/assets/uploads/2010/06/synctoy-preview.png)]

You can then choose one of three modes ("Synchronize", "Echo" and "Contribute") to resolve the differences.

Lastly, it comes with `SyncToyCmd` for creating and synchronizing folder pairs from the CLI or a Scheduled Task.

Comment: I tried installing SyncToy but it insists that it needs a really old version of the .NET framework installed (v2.0.50727). I appear to have v4.7.1 or later already installed! I don't trust software that old to be secure, so I'll try a different tool.

Comment: A valid concern! But the .NET Framework (even 2.0) is still fully supported by Microsoft. No need to manually install—you can [enable it directly in the Windows 10 Control Panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/dotnet-35-windows-10#enable-the-net-framework-35-in-control-panel).

Comment: I believe as of 2020-Dec-02 Microsoft's "requirement" link for this download does not include support for Windows 10. My specific concern is support for GPT partitioned hard drives over 2 Terabytes which pre-Windows 10 did not support... I think.

Answer (score 3):

You can use git for exactly this purpose. Basically, you create a git repository in folder `A` (the repo is in `A/.git`), then copy `A/.git` to `B/.git`, then change to `B` folder and compare simply by running git diff.
And the `--exclude` functionality can be achieved with `.gitignore`.

So, sticking to your example (but using bash shell on Linux):

```
# Create a Git repo in current_vss
pushd current_vss
printf ".svn\n*.vspscc\n*.scc" >> .gitignore
git init && git add . && git commit -m 'initial'
popd

# Copy the repo to current_svn and compare
cp -r current_vss/.git* current_svn/
pushd current_svn
git diff
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try:
[Araxis Merge](https://www.araxis.com/merge/index.en)?
It allows you to visualize changes and selectively merge specific differences in files and folders.